# imageButton draw in bottom of the layout

Tags: android, draw, imagebutton

I have ImageButton which create inside the code,

```
    // Create Button 
    ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton(mContext);
    imageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button);

    imageButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    LayoutParams myParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    addContentView(imageButton, myParams);
```

How can i draw it in the bottom of the layout ?

Comment: which layout do you use to contain the button ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp= (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)myButton.getLayoutParams(); 
lp.layout_gravity=Gravity.BOTTOM; 
myButton.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: I dont see layout_gravity inside lp

Comment: You will have to try out 2 ways and see which works. myButton.setGravity(); or lp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM.